# Approach on debugging page with a bunch of javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have more general question on how you usually approach on debugging page  with tons of javascript (mostly third-party add-ons) and event watchers to discover the problematic line, which in my case causes the Chrome to crash or Firefox to freeze?

I have a landing page with many external dependencies: the usual suspects like jquery and bootstrap, but also many add-ons like sliders, re-size watchers. When I re-size there is a micro-freeze on Firefox and a crash on Chrome. This is from any block of code (some watchers most probably).

After page crashes I lose all of my dev tool data. Firebug doesn't have the timing control over scripts execution, and if I start with breakpoints I have to put dozens.

How you usually proceeding to identify the script that causes the problem and further more the block of code?

Comment: The most basic approach is divide-and-conquer (there are many examples on www).

Comment: Yeah - this is good one to start with. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I start with breakpoints I have to put dozens.

I used to have this problem a lot back with Internet Explorer 4/5.  Those browsers made such poor use of memory that almost any significant error wold result in the browser crashing.  And even before it did, the browser debugging tools were far, far worse than the Chrome ones.  So what did I do?  Sadly, `debugger` and `console.log`.

You must have *some* idea, or ideas, as to where the problem lies, so just start at wherever you are certain your code is working and add a `console.log` (if you can still see the logs up to the crash) or a `debugger` (if you can't) to every point along the way to the crash.  Eventually you won't make it to one of your debugging statements, and then you'll know that the problem is in-between that statement and the previous one.

It's a really lame way to debug, I know, and as you said you will have to add a lot of debugging statements, but sometimes it's all you have.

Comment: I completely understand and I see that it is like braided fish cord. I've been in these situations before, but usually script execution completely freezes the browser and then I have at least idea of which file contains the script. Now the thing is tricky and causes just a little freeze of the browser (at least on my machine)

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't have to add every debugging statement at once.  If you think the problem could be in five different palces, just add one debugging statement to each.  Then once you've figured out which palce is to blame you can add heavier debugging statements to determine where exactly in the place it's occurring.  That way you don't have to add every debugging statement up front.

Comment: I was thinking about cutting the functionality piece by piece until the problem disappears and the put back the last thing. This way I'll the define the script file first.